# Update Manager offers update for ibus-hangul & nabi packages but they can't be installed

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, dependencies

Update Manager offers update for ibus-hangul & nabi packages but they can't be installed (i can't check their checkboxes). Why? What unmet dependencies they have and how i can met them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this same problem, and have since upgrading to the 12.04 beta.  Now I'm on the full version, but these two packages are still hanging around, exactly as the original poster describes.  Help!

Comment: See: I've launched Synaptic, and I've update that packages manually (by hands (?), sorry for my English) without any problems. Just install this program, type in filter "ibus-hangul", select it and click "upgrage" in context menu of this item.

Comment: Awesome!  Worked perfectly!  Thanks for replying to my answer... (I think we're using this forum all wrong, but we figured it out!)

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm not sure on why this is happening (I arrived here searching for the same question), you don't have to install/launch Synaptic. You can use the command `sudo apt-get install ibus-hangul nabi` instead.